# Using raw pointers without allocating memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I would like to ask about my approach to using pointers raw pointers without allocating any memory using pointers. I am working on an application, that is simulating classical cashdesk. So I have a class CashDesk, which is containing vectors of Items and vector of Orders, which are classes to represent items and orders. Furthermore, I want the Order class to contain a vector, which would be a vector of pointers to Item – I don't want to store the object multiple times in different orders, because it makes no sense to me. Through the pointers in Order, I only want to be able to access properties of the class Item, there is no allocating of memory using the pointers.

Simplified code:

```
class CashDesk {
 vector<Item> items;
 vector<Order> orders;
}
class Order {
 vector<Item*> ItemsInOrder;
}
```

Class Item containing only structured data – information about the Item.

I create all objects at the level of the CashDesk class – create instance of Item when needed and push it to items vector.

I have been told that I should avoid using raw pointers unless there is no another option. The important thing is that I don't use any memory allocation using pointers – really using the pointer in terms of pointing at the object and accessing it's properties. Should I rather use something like unique_ptr, or completely different approach?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Creating an object *involves* memory allocation.

Comment: Right, I meant that I don't allocate any memory using pointers – only create the object as described.

Comment: Why does the `CashDesk` own the items that the `Order` references? This code design seems odd to me and there can easily be lots of dangling pointer issues croping up (e.g.: when you modify the `items` vector, invalidating all pointers to those items). There is most likely a better design choice

Comment: Reference the elements of vectors by their index, not by pointers.

Comment: Just have `Order` be an vector of index values in `CashDesk::items` instead of a vector of pointers.  That is `vector<size_t> ItemsInOrder`

Comment: Thank you for response. The thing is that I want to be able to access the Item properties through order. For example to sum the order. So I need to be able to get the price of the item.

Comment: If `vector<size_t> ItemsInOrder`, then you'd do `money_t Order::Sum(CashDeck& deck) const { money_t result; for(auto i : ItemsInOrder) { result += deck.item(i).money; } return result; }`

Answer (score 2):

> I have been told that I should avoid using raw pointers unless there is no another option.

You have been told something subtly wrong. You should avoid *owning* raw pointers, but non-owning raw pointers are perfectly fine.

You will have to ensure that the elements of `Order::itemsInOrder` aren't invalidated by operations on `CashDesk::items`, but that co-ordination should be within the `private` parts of `CashDesk`.

You could be more explicit about the lack of ownership semantic, by using `std::vector<Item>::iterator` in place of `Item *`, but that doesn't change any behaviour (a conforming implementation *may* implement `std::vector<Item>::iterator` as an alias of `Item *`)

Comment: Usual warning when keeping references to vector elements: beware of reallocations!